# Adding namespace to an xsd element

Tags: xml, xsd, hl7-fhir

I have spent good amount of hours trying to make this XSD conform with the XML payload i have here, the error i get presently is "Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'Patient'."

schema.xml

```
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<id value="93c4260b-8ff3-420a-bbe4-2f8fee6a06f7"/>
<meta>
    <lastUpdated value="2019-07-02T11:16:51.120-04:00"/>
</meta>
<type value="searchset"/>
<total value="1"/>
<link>
    <relation value="self"/>
    <url value="https://my-url/Patient?identifier=1.3.6.1.4.1.12009.1.40.1%7C47211&amp;link=210988314"/>
</link>
<entry>
    <fullUrl value="https://my-url/Patient/40-141247"/>
    <resource>
        <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <id value="40-141227247"/>
            <link>
                <other>
                    <reference value="Patient/31-124278"/>
                </other>
                <type value="seealso"/>
            </link>
            <link>
                <other>
                    <reference value="Patient/40-133347"/>
                </other>
                <type value="seealso"/>
            </link>
        </Patient>
    </resource>
</entry>
    <entry>
    <fullUrl value="https://my-url/Patient/40-141227"/>
    <resource>
        <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <id value="40-141227247"/>
            <link>
                <other>
                    <reference value="Patient/31-124760"/>
                </other>
                <type value="seealso"/>
            </link>
            <link>
                <other>
                    <reference value="Patient/40-133347"/>
                </other>
                <type value="seealso"/>
            </link>
        </Patient>
    </resource>
</entry>
```

schema.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" targetNamespace="http://hl7.org/fhir" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" schemaLocation="fhir-xhtml.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="Bundle">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="id"/>
        <xs:element ref="meta"/>
        <xs:element ref="type"/>
        <xs:element ref="total"/>
        <xs:element ref="link"/>
        <xs:element ref="entry"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   <!--  <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/> -->
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="meta">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="lastUpdated"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="lastUpdated">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="total">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="entry">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="fullUrl"/>
        <xs:element ref="resource"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="fullUrl">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="resource">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Patient"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Patient">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="id"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="link"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="id">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="type">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="link">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="other"/>
          <xs:element ref="type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="relation"/>
          <xs:element ref="url"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="other">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="reference"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="reference">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="relation">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="url">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have checked online to see if i can get a clue on resolving this for a particular element, no luck yet. I will any help here.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<xs:element name="Patient">` definition just use 'optional' for the value attribute, e.g.

```
<xs:attribute name="value" use="optional"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instance is valid against the official FHIR schema.  Given the commented 'value' element in the schema fragment posted, it appears you've adjusted your schema somehow.  If you stick with the official schema, you'll be fine.